# Integration of Vitamio in Android App

Tags: android, stream, vitamio

I have created an App to stream h264 videos over RTSP. Using Android's videoview i got long buffertimes and a latency around 5 seconds. From what I have read the easiest way to improve this is to use Vitamio SDK. The documentation on their page is very small and I have trouble importing it. This is the official HowTo https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/wiki/How-to-integrate-Vitamio-on-your-own-project%3F

I don't know how to this properly, how do I create the .jar file? Thanks in advance for any help guys

Comment: look at [this instructions](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/wiki/How-to-integrate-Vitamio-on-your-own-project%3F)

Comment: These are the ones I posted but I am not sure how to do it? Do I Import both Vitamio and VitamioListActivity into eclipse and Export them as .jar file? then take /vitamio/res and /vitamio/libs from the same Folder and put them into the root of my Project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest simplest way to achieve it without jar

1) `import Vitamio library` in your eclipse.

2) right click on your own project -> Properties -> Android -> `Add` -> select vitamio library which you have imported in eclipse

3) `configure your manifest` file by adding an activity declaration as mentioned:

```
        <activity
        android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

4) You are ready to go, for `reference` you can look at any demo activity from VitamioListActivity project , i.e.: VideoViewDemo.java

Comment: I want to thank you a lot good sir! That's super helpful. If you allow me one more question, I am playing around with the demo right now and while it displays the stream correctly, I get a latency of up to 5 seconds. Is this based on my slow Hardware or are there Options to increase Speed?

Thank you again!

Comment: @user3541930: I'm glad to help. latency depends upon your network speed and modem capacity of your device.