# How to import Vitamio libs to android app

Tags: android, vitamio

I writing an video player and using https://www.vitamio.org. I read the docs but I don't give me how to import libs to my app. I try to download example and it can't run. I want to ask:
1. How to import it to my app.
2. I can install my app without Vitamio libs and install later(if user want).

Comment: Have you checked out the Demo app? It will be better than any answer I'd say. Also, you didn't mention which IDE you're using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integration of Vitamio in Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606812/integration-of-vitamio-in-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

Download vitamio for andorid from [here](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle)

Don't forget to copy lib project in your workspace directory, Import in eclipse and

then add library to your project, Right Click on your Project -> Properties and then [add like this](http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?imgurl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9uWl.jpg&imgrefurl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr&h=698&w=724&tbnid=wLg4ZdWtvB-QbM:&zoom=1&docid=DTB5q0S9iDK5FM&ei=wYxRVcu3JMvSUejWgJAH&tbm=isch&ved=0CFUQMygxMDE)

One thing more I want to tell you may be you can't test the app on emulator of Intel, Try to test you app on device.

Also there is a demo projects with the library, you can check out them also

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that the linked Github project is still using an old version of Vitamio.