# live streaming using vitamio library

Tags: android, streaming, live, vitamio

I am trying to stream live video from Spydriod to video view in Vitamio. It is streaming on VLC palyer, but when I try it on vitamio all I see is just a black screen. I have searched internet and tried many solution, but nothing really solved the issue. Following are links that i visited.

https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/18

[Can't run live stream using Vitamio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789244/cant-run-live-stream-using-vitamio)

[Integration of Vitamio in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606812/integration-of-vitamio-in-android-app)

There also no errors in LogFile. Below is the code of my main activity.

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.sidraaleem.project;

    import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import java.util.HashMap;

import io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker;
import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private String path;
    //private HashMap<String, String> options;
    private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vitamio_videoView);


        if (LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this)) //it will check the include library of Vitamio
            return;
        path = "rtsp://192.168.1.2:8086";
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
              });
    }
}
```

Also in manifest.xml I have added the permissions stated below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But nothing turned out to be fruitful. Please help me I am totally stuck with this issue.